# How many times does one number divide into another, and how much is left over?

Tags: algorithm, delphi, integer

I need an algorithm in Delphi to generate partitions for a specified integer value.

Example: for 13 if 5 is specified as the max value for partition it will give 5,5,3; if 4 is specified as max partition value the result should be 4,4,4,1, and so on.

Comment: Are all but the last number equal to the max value? In that case you can simply use `n = max * (n div max) + (n mod max)`

Comment: Have you attempted this?  Given that I just solved this in like 2 minutes and the nature of this (it's very short and simple), it's seems like a homework assignment that you need to accomplish yourself.

Comment: Sorry, I searched for it but didn't find it unti l Read the Howto. thnx a lot..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's simple enough to solve the problem using `div` and `mod`. Here's an example program that I don't think needs any further explanation:

```
program IntegerPartitions;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

function Partitions(const Total, Part: Integer): TArray<Integer>;
var
  Count: Integer;
  Rem: Integer;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Assert(Total>0);
  Assert(Part>0);

  Count := Total div Part;
  Rem := Total mod Part;
  if Rem=0 then
    SetLength(Result, Count)
  else
    SetLength(Result, Count+1);
  for i := 0 to Count-1 do
    Result[i] := Part;
  if Rem<>0 then
    Result[Count] := Rem;
end;

var
  Value: Integer;

begin
  for Value in Partitions(13, 5) do
    Writeln(Value);
  Readln;
end.
```